# The data contain levels not found in the data

Tags: r, dataframe, prediction, confusion-matrix, levels

I am using the following function but I get this error `The data contain levels not found in the data` . Any idea what I have to do?

`confusionMatrix(reference = as.factor(AAA), data = BBB, mode='everything')`

**AAA**

```
c("A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "B", "C", "E", "A", "A", "B", "C", 
"A", "L", "C", "C", "C", "C", "G", "B", "B", "I", "A", "C", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "L", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", 
"C", "C", "I", "M", "B", "C", "B", "C", "B", "C", "B", "E", "B", 
"C", "C", "A", "B", "L", "C", "G", "C", "G", "A", "B", "A", "B", 
"C", "B", "E", "A", "C", "G", "B", "C", "E", "L", "A", "K", "B", 
"C", "G", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "C", "G", "A", "B", "A", "C", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "G", "B", "I", "B", "A", "B", "B", "L", 
"B", "E", "B", "G", "G", "A", "G", "L", "A", "B", "C", "C", "B", 
"C", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "G", "C", "C", "A", "B", "A", "E", 
"C", "B", "B", "C", "L", "C", "C", "K", "G", "I", "A", "B", "C", 
"B", "B", "B", "C", "I", "C", "L", "B", "C", "E", "C", "C", "B", 
"C", "E", "C", "G", "C", "B", "A", "A", "C", "A", "L", "C", "B", 
"B", "C", "B", "G", "C", "B", "G", "A", "B", "A", "I", "C", "E", 
"B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "L", "E", "C", "B", "C", "A", 
"C", "G", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "L", "A", "C", 
"C", "I", "A", "M", "K", "A", "B", "C", "C", "I", "L", "E", "B", 
"L", "B", "E", "B", "K", "M", "L", "C", "C", "G", "A", "A", "I", 
"G", "A", "B", "C", "K", "E", "C", "G", "L", "C", "E", "L", "A", 
"A", "C", "L", "A", "B", "G", "C", "C", "B", "B", "C", "G", "A", 
"C", "E", "G", "B", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "B", "A", 
"C", "C", "L", "C", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", 
"B", "C", "C", "A", "G", "A", "C", "A", "A", "G", "C", "E", "A", 
"B", "G", "L", "M", "A", "B", "E", "B", "K", "A", "B", "C", "B", 
"B", "C", "B", "E", "C", "G", "B", "C", "B", "I", "A", "C", "A", 
"C", "C", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "L", "A", "C", "B", "I", "B", 
"C", "A", "L", "C", "B", "A", "A", "B", "L", "A", "A", "A", "C", 
"A", "B", "K", "C", "B", "I", "B", "C", "L", "B", "C", "B", "C", 
"C", "C", "B", "B", "G", "E", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", 
"I", "A", "B", "B", "C", "K", "B", "G", "L", "A", "C", "A", "B", 
"I", "B", "G", "A", "B", "C", "C", "L", "A", "A", "C", "L", "C", 
"A", "C", "A", "B", "C", "L", "C", "C", "B", "G", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "G", "I", "I", "K", "C", "B", "G", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "G", "K", "E", "I", "C", "E", "G", "G", "A", 
"B", "E", "M", "C", "C", "B", "C", "B", "K", "B", "A", "A", "C", 
"C", "I", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "G", "C", 
"G", "C", "C", "C", "E", "E", "L", "C", "I", "E", "B", "B", "C", 
"A", "C", "I", "C", "L", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "C", 
"B", "G", "C", "B", "C", "A", "E", "B", "L", "B", "G", "A", "B", 
"B", "A", "E", "C", "G", "C", "G", "B", "A", "A", "B", "S", "B", 
"E", "G", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C", "L", "A", "L", "B", "A", "I", 
"I", "C", "A", "L", "B", "G", "C", "A", "B", "B", "L", "L", "C", 
"C", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "B", "L", "B", "G", "E", "B", "G", 
"B", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "E", "B", "E", "C", "B", "G", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "G", "C", "K", "C", "A", "G", "B", 
"G", "A", "B", "C", "B", "G", "A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"E", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "E", "A", "B", "E", "I", "A", "A", 
"G", "L", "A", "A", "M", "A", "C", "G", "G", "B", "B", "G", "C", 
"A", "B", "B", "E", "C", "C", "B", "A", "E", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "E", "L", "A", "B", "A", "B", "E", "B", "I", "A", "G", "B", 
"B", "A", "B", "B", "E", "B", "A", "B", "L", "C", "L", "C", "L", 
"C", "A", "C", "C", "B", "C", "B", "L", "A", "C", "I", "A", "A", 
"C", "B", "C", "E", "C", "I", "G", "G", "C", "A", "B", "B", "C", 
"I", "I", "M", "C", "E", "A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "C", "B", "C", 
"C", "E", "C", "C", "A", "I", "C", "C", "E", "B", "B", "E", "E", 
"C", "A", "M", "G", "B", "C", "A", "C", "C", "B", "B", "A", "B", 
"B", "A", "G", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "G", "C", "E", "C", 
"E", "G", "B", "L", "C", "A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "I", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "C", "C", "A", 
"A", "B", "L", "A", "C", "C", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "K", "A", 
"C", "I", "A", "C", "A", "E", "A", "B", "B", "B", "I", "E", "A", 
"A", "B", "E", "A", "B", "M", "C", "A", "B", "I", "A", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "B", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "B", "C", "E", "I", 
"L", "S", "L", "M", "A", "B", "B", "C", "B", "C", "B", "C", "A", 
"A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "M", "A", "I", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "I", "A", "M", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "C", "G", "A", "B", 
"C", "C", "L", "A", "B", "G", "I", "A", "B", "C", "E", "C", "B", 
"B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "G", "C", "L", "B", "E", 
"B", "C", "B", "A", "B", "E", "L", "B", "C", "I", "A", "B", "B", 
"C", "B", "C", "B", "C", "B", "B")
```

**BBB**

```
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), levels = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "L"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: You won't get it into the first format, that's just how R prints objects. But more importantly, why do you want it in that format?

Comment: Since I get the following error when I use ConfusionMAtrix function: 
  "The data contain levels not found in the data."

Comment: Use the `droplevels()` function.

Comment: It gave the same exact error

Comment: Show us your whole code, how you are saving this data, how you are reading it, and how you are calling the confusion matrix function. Anyway, check that both your y and x have the same levels.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to convert `factor` to `character`, e.g.,

```
x <- as.character(x)
```

or

```
x <- levels(x)[x]
```

then you run `dput(x)` and will see the desired format.